# Handling pop ups using selenium with perl

Tags: perl, selenium, popup

I want a solution for the following scenario:
In a page I am uploading an xml and while clicking on the upload button I am going to recieve an pop up for confirmation (I am able to detect this), after this again I am recieving an pop up which I am not able to detect (The page is still getting loaded in the browser ). Kindly help me to sort this out .

I have tried with many solutions for this like: get window ids,titles .

Thanks

Comment: What kind of popup is it javascript or a new browser window? Also please share the exact code you tried? Any error messages?

Comment: It is a java script and not a new browser window amey....I dont have the code right now  but will try to upload tomorrow.....
Error messages:The code detects the first pop up and for the second pop up, server says no such pop up....

Comment: Also I am assuming you are using Selenium RC as compared to selenium webdriver, right?

Comment: Yeah am using Selenium RC with WWW::Selenium perl package..

Answer (score 1):

You can you use -

```
$sel->get_confirmation()
```

This retrieves the message of a JavaScript confirmation dialog generated duringthe previous action. By default, the confirm function will return true, having the same effectas manually clicking OK. This can be changed by prior execution of thechooseCancelOnNextConfirmation command. If an confirmation is generatedbut you do not get/verify it, the next Selenium action will fail.

NOTE: under Selenium, JavaScript confirmations will NOT pop up a visibledialog.

NOTE: Selenium does NOT support JavaScript confirmations that aregenerated in a page's onload() event handler. In this case a visibledialog WILL be generated and Selenium will hang until you manually clickOK.

Returns the message of the most recent JavaScript confirmation dialog.

You should always refer to [WWW::Selenium - Perl Client](http://search.cpan.org/~lukec/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.13/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm) while working with perl and RC.

Comment: Hey thanks ......But I have tried everything you have said above but your second NOTE is something that I did not know......And I do refer to www selenium perl...........Thanks again....

Comment: I have found what is the problem @amey.I am tring to upload an file which is not actually not permitted due to some security issues with firefox.There was actually an work around for this 
http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2006/03/29/file-upload-with-selenium/
which will not work with latest Selenium RC with Firefox since firefox have removed the support for enablePrivilege 
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/944433.
So it is a mandate to shift to WEBDRIVER it seems.............
http://git.erp5.org/gitweb/erp5.git/commitdiff/06898bbfae4f238b7e79ce05048646529216064e
Thanks for your support....

Answer (score 0):

I have found what is the problem @amey ...I am tring to upload an file which is not actually not permitted due to some security issues with firefox... There was actually an work around for this 
[**http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2006/03/29/file-upload-with-selenium/**](http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2006/03/29/file-upload-with-selenium/)
.....Which will not work with latest Selenium RC with Firefox since firefox have removed the support for enablePrivilege 
[**https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/944433.**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/944433.)
So it is a mandate to shift to WEBDRIVER it seems.............
[**http://git.erp5.org/gitweb/erp5.git/commitdiff/06898bbfae4f238b7e79ce05048646529216064e**](http://git.erp5.org/gitweb/erp5.git/commitdiff/06898bbfae4f238b7e79ce05048646529216064e)
Thanks for your support....

Answer (score 0):

my solution was using the function:

`$driver->execute_script("Events.invokeEvent('UserDetailPage:UserDetailScreen:UserDetailToolbarButtonSet:UserDetailToolbarButtons_DeleteUserButton_act', true);");`

analyzing what the javascript code does when the Accept button was pressed. and executing that code in the function.